# How to prevent logout from app running as agent

Tags: cocoa, user-agent, nsapplication-delegate

The sample menu bar app is a agent as its LSUIElement is TRUE.
I want to prevent logout on certain conditions.

I tried with - (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender.
But I never receive this message when user logs out.

But without , I am able to prevent logout as well.

Need an alternative solution so as to prevent  logout.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use LSUIElement in the plist. Instead on launch use:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

I verified that applicationShouldTerminate: is in fact called when done this way.

Comment: applicationShouldTerminate: is in fact getting called when we trying to quit menu bar app using commadn+q. Nothing is preventing the logout. NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory is in fact equivalent to LSUIElement set to 1 in Info.plist.

Comment: applicationShouldTerminate: is in fact getting called for me on logout. However, I am unable to prevent the logout.

Comment: Any other ways to prevent logout or do a graceful exit. My App is launch agent with LSUIElement =1 .